# does ember.js care whether its called at the top or at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

So after looking at a few examples it looks like ember apps call 'ember.js' and
'jquery.js' at the top/head of an html page.

All the jquery sites I worked on called jquery at the bottom of the page.
(just before the ending body tag)
I want to migrate these sites to ember bit by bit...

So the question is, when developing an ember.js application, should 
the scripts be included/called first or last

Answer (score 1):

Javascript library/framework must be called before the scripts that use the library/framework. That is why you e.g. get a "$ is not defined" error when jQuery is linked at the bottom of the HTML structure and there's a jQuery code before the library is loaded.

So, the thing you need to keep in mind is to load ember.js before you use it. Of course, best website-performance/SEO practice is to keep your scripts "low", before the closing `<body>` tag.